# How to migrate Firefox bookmarks with tags to Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, bookmarks

Firefox exports HTML without tags, or else as a JSON file. Since Chrome doesn't do tagging, a workaround would be to put the tags in the title so that text is still searchable once imported to Chrome.

Is there an alternative way to get all my tags into the title within firefox, or using an online service or other tool?

Comment: In case you would like to see Google Chrome implement bookmark labeling / tagging, you can star the following issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17536

Answer (score -1):

Try **Xmarks Sync** to synchronize your bookmarks across multiple browsers and machines. It is available for Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc. Hope this solves your problem.

[Xmarks Firefox Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/)

[Xmarks Chrome Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xmarks-bookmark-sync/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla?hl=en)

Comment: Xmarks syncs bookmarks between Firefox and Chrome, but the tags get left behind in Chrome, so it doesn't actually solve this problem.